# Opeing Solidworks assembly file in Inventor, parts gets unconstrained

Tags: c#, vb.net, solidworks, autodesk-inventor

When i try to open up Solidworks assembly file  (SLDASM) in Inventor, the parts gets unconstrained? Those files are constrained in Solidworks but things get unconstrained when I load the same file in Inventor?

Is there any programming help to preserve the mates files in solidworks so that it will be preserved when I open it in Inventor?

Thanks  !

Comment: I also want to do perform same task. Did you find anything?

Comment: No not yet..my bad luck .:(

Comment: You can try exporting to a STEP file and using it in inventor.

Answer (score 1):

When translating files, only the geometry is translated.  You lose all feature information and also the constraints when translating assemblies.  This is typical of all CAD systems, not just Inventor.